# I got an error while implementing swipe tabs in IONIC 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

## SO FAR I HAVE DONE IS

```
npm install ionic2-super-tabs --save
```

### Imported in app.module.ts file

```
import { SuperTabsModule } from 'ionic2-super-tabs';



imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    SuperTabsModule

  ],
```

My Tabs.html file

```
<super-tabs>
    <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab1Root" title="First page"></super-tab>
    <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab1Root" title="Second page"></super-tab>
    <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab1Root" title="Third page"></super-tab>
</super-tabs>
```

### Error what i am getting

[image]

Comment: are you using lazy loading?

Comment: I have tried both

Comment: I suspect it has to do with lazy loading and importing of the module.. anyway the library owner seems to have an example project https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs-example

Comment: they are importing import { SuperTabsModule } from '../ionic2-super-tabs/src'; this gives me error module not found ../ionic2-super-tabs/src

Comment: that maybe because they havent used library from node_modules... I think you need to use _forRoot_ but cant be sure

Comment: i did that too...i almost spent my whole day to achieve this but still its not working

Comment: Do you know how can i change the background color of ionic tab?

Answer (score 0):

You should be importing the module like this instead
{
...
  SuperTabsModule.forRoot(),
..
}

Answer (score 0):

it's [root] instead of tabRoot

Answer (score 0):

**Look this Link**: https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs/issues/269

SuperTabs doesn't use the attribute tabRoot it uses root:

Quick Example (from the docs)

```
<super-tabs>
  <super-tab [root]="page1" title="First page"></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="page2" title="Second page"></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="page3" title="Third page"></super-tab>
</super-tabs>
```

I had a lot of Problems because of the ionic2-super-tabs versions I used ionic2-super-tabs": "^4.1.4, now I'm using ionic2-super-tabs": "^4.3.0 and its runing with no BUG